# Test max output of a USB charger

Tags: usb-c

I bought a 65W charger for my phone and laptops and notice really slow charging speeds. Now I would like to test said charger if it actually is able to deliver said 65W or if maybe the problem is something else.

ATTN: I am not an electrical engineer!

So my first thought was to charge my phone with the charger and use app (e.g. "Ampere") to monitor charging. Problem: Phone may not support or use full 65W. Also, the cable might be problematic.

Second thought: Use a multimeter. Yet I wouldn't know where to measure on a typical charger USB (C) - port.

Anyone here who can point me in the right direction?

PS: Charger is a "KingMa 65W GaN" from "KingMa Electronics Co., Limited"

Comment: There is signaling (several different flavors) between phones and chargers that control the allowable charge rate, and it's much more likely that the problem is the phone and the charger disagreeing on the type of signaling, or the cable being bad/incompatible, than that the charger can't deliver rated power. And testing it properly is more complicated than you probably want to get into.

Comment: Thanks for the honest answer. Thought so already.

Comment: Buy a USB-PD power meter, plug it inline with your laptop, and see what the laptop is requesting and what the supply is delivering.

Comment: Are both the phone and the laptop suffer the slow charging, or the phone alone? The phone may be only QC-compatible. And even if the phone draws only 1W or 2W, the laptop output is reduced to 45W. And yes, USB-PD meters do exist, but the one I god not so long ago costs more than half of your charger price.

Comment: What kind of CORD are you using?   Not all USB cords are created equal.  If you got your cord from Dollar Tree, it'll have VERY thin wires inside (which will limit the max current ergo max power).   You could try a quality cord and see if that helps (cheap solution)

Comment: This is kinda solved. Unfortunately, I cannot report a solution to how to MEASURE the output.
Specifically, it was the cable.